# Как определить выбранный option в контроллере Sptring. Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Итак, есть некоторый Java код, а также html. У меня есть список категорий товара, человек сам выбирает под какую категорию под какую категорию подходит вводимый им товар.
Проблема такова: я не знаю как определить в своём контроллере Spring какая категория была выбрана. Вывод всех категорий я сделал списком из option тегов
Вот html код:

```
               <div class="category">
                    <h6>Choose category</h6>
                    <label>
                        <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
                            <option th:each="category : ${categories}" th:text="${category}"></option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
               </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена! Необходимо добавить параметр name="category" в тег select.
После чего в контроллере Spring брать данные с помощью аннотации RequestParam("category") String category.
Таким образом, в переменной categoru будет заложено value того option'а, что был выбран